# Induction from latching relay at AC lines voltage

Tags: relay, induction

I am using an AC [latching relay](https://new.abb.com/products/2TAZ312000R2011/e290-16-10-230) in my house to switch the same LED light from three or more places. Somehow the LED lamp seems to be very sensitive to parasitic voltages, because when I engage one of the momentary switches in my installation, I see a dim flash of some of the LEDs. Most notably, there is a flash on every state change of the switch (and hence, of the relay as well). I.e. if I press the switch to turn the lights off and still leave it pressed for another two seconds, I see a first flash after first pressing, and a second flash after finally releasing the switch.

This leads me to conclude (without having made further, transient measurements), that this is due to self-induction from the relay coil. I suppose the induction voltage is capacitively coupled over the already opened relay contact to the LED lamp and back to the neutral conductor. Moreover, the intensity of the flashes varies, which I would explain by the dependency of the induction on the current phase angle during switching (switching during zero-crossing = no induction).

Now, with most of the devices this behavior would go unnoticed, and I would not care, but the LED lamp being peculiar as it is gives one the impression that my installation isn't quite right. So I would like to get rid of this effect, if possible. I also can hardly imagine that this isn't observed in some other of the possibly millions of similar applications around the world.

Is there anything I can do about this with reasonable (and standard compliant) measures?

Comment: Do the LEDs do that in a normal switched light fixture? Maybe it's the LEDs, there's a lot of junk out there.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine: no, they don't. I have to note that these are not standard low wattage lamps but rather 50W floodlights (I like it bright...). I have also experienced low quality with cheap China brand floodlights (failing early), but the ones that I have now seem to be very reliable. As far as I was able to tell, they are 56 LEDs in series with some stabilizing for every group of like 10 LEDs. If you say junk, do you mean that proper cicuitry will normally take care of those stray current effects I have observed?

Comment: It's more based on design.  I have one cheapie LED screw-in that flickers badly whenever the refrigerator cycles. That LED seems to be nothing but a series string of emitters with a resistor. Look at the V-I chart on any raw LED emitter and you'll see the problem -  small voltage changes cause huge current changes.  See also the many LED designs that play badly with dimmers that leak current through the bulb when off, and will flash on momentary switch transition leakage. Or it could be reacting to inductive kick from the relay coil sharing its power supply.    Stuff like that.